# When arg max - f(x) = arg min f(x)

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar function. It is true that
$$
\arg \max_{x} \{ -f(x) \} = \arg \min_{x} f(x)
$$
or does it depend on the specific $f$ ?

Comment: i don't think it depends on properties of $f$, unless you have multiple extrema and you define these functions to fix exactly one of the values according to some rule...

Comment: You are making the assumption that (at least one of) these exist

Comment: @Henry If there is no minimizer of $f$ then both sets will be empty, so no assumption about existence of a minimum is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$f(x) \leq f(y) \Leftrightarrow -f(x)\geq -f(y)$

Comment: Ok, $\arg \max_{x} f(x) = \{ x | \forall y: f(y) \leq f(x) \}$. So you are suggesting that: $\arg \max_{x} -f(x) = \{ x | \forall y: -f(y) \leq -f(x) \} = \{ x | \forall y: f(y) \geq f(x) \} = \arg \min_{x} f(x)$ ? Am I right?